# Facebook user authentication on app server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

All I want is to find at least one working solution for this simple thing.
I want to determine what facebook user making request to my FB canvas application. I also want the mechanism to take into account cases when user logs off or re-logs on.
I've really broken my head on that :(

Ways i've already tried:
1) Getting and parsing signed_request param while user's initial request to the application. Cons: the canvas main page is the only place to get it. I never know what user is doing next actions.
2) Using fbsr cookie. Cons: sometimes i get error when trying to exchange cookie's code to user's access token. I still cant reproduce it, it just occurs. Btw, does it work at your?
3) Handling every get/post request at client side and adding user's access token being retrieved by JS SDK to the request. Doesnt seem to be a good way.

Well, that's it. What im doing wrong? Will be thankfull a lot for any working solution.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Getting and parsing signed_request param while user's initial request to the application. Cons: the canvas main page is the only place to get it. I never know what user is doing next actions.

Well then just put the parsed signed request into the session …

That’s what I usually do – every time `Facebook::getSignedRequest` results in something other then `null`, I write it into my session (so I don’t miss if it gets updated, f.e. by the user liking the page).

Comment: You put it to the session, then other user logs into facebook but remains old user for your app.

Comment: When another user logs in, the app is called again in the iframe by Facebook, so there’ll be a new signed request also.

Comment: If my friend logs into fb in other window, the error popup message is displayed on the original tab. I close it and continue working under my account.

Comment: Well, who _does_ that – login in to a website in another window of the same browser on the same machine …? I’d say that’s a very special use case, and not the normal one.

Comment: What if my site is money-sensitive? I hoped there should be a way for detecting what exact user is doing operation at the moment but i can see the one. Also, i cant understand why cookie code is sometimes wrong...